# How to use expect to spawn with arguments from command line?

Tags: shell, tcl, expect

Suppose that I call `my.exp` by

```
my.exp cmd a b c d ...
```

I want to pass all the arguments of my.exp to spawn. But I don't find a way to do so. Is there a way to do it with expect? Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

spawn $argv
...
```

Comment: Expect uses the [Tcl language](http://www.tcl.tk/). You need to learn Tcl before you can write Expect scripts. If you are more comfortable with shell syntax you can try my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd want to use tcl's [argument expansion](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M9) syntax to do this:

```
spawn {*}$argv
```

## Example

### my.exp:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
log_user 0
puts "Spawning '$argv'"
spawn {*}$argv
expect *foo* { puts "Got: '[string trim $expect_out(buffer)]'" }
```

### Usage:

```sh
$ ./my.exp echo foo bar
Spawning 'echo foo bar'
Got: 'foo bar'
```

Comment: The correct path agnostic shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env -S expect -f`

Comment: @LéaGris Huh? No version of `env` I have has an `-S` option, nor do they take arguments to the command being run (Despite the man pages saying they do, it's all treated as a single string that's the name of the command so you get errors about `expect -f` not being found).

Comment: (It appears to be a limitation of how many OSes parse shebangs to decide what to run; in `execve(2)`, they split the line at the first space into the command and a single optional argument that is the rest of the line.)

Comment: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html → `-S, --split-string=S process and split S into separate arguments; used to pass multiple arguments on shebang lines` See also: https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/668306ed86c8c79b0af0db8b9c882654ebb66db2

Comment: @LéaGris not on Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04. Or NetBSD 9.0 or OpenBSD 6.7...

Comment: The `-f` option to `expect` is usually not needed, especially once the script has been debugged.

Comment: @DonalFellows Yeah, not sure why the other guy is calling an invocation that doesn't work on any OS I have available the 'correct' one, especially when what OP and I use works fine.